# Repeated use of boost::geometry::intersection in a loop

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I have a base multipolygon `B` and a number of other multipolygons `p_0, p_1, p_2, ...` each of which has a weight `w_0, w_1, w_2, ...`.

I would like to:

- Calculate the area of intersection of `B` and `p_0` and multiply this area by `w_0`.
- Difference `B` and `p_0` to form a new multipolygon `B_1` which is `B` with `p_0` cut out of it.
- Calculate the area of intersection of `B_1` and `p_1` and multiply this area by `w_1`.
- Difference `B_1` and `p_1` to form a new multipolygon `B_2` which is `B_1` with `p_1` cut out of it.
- And so on...

I am trying to do this using the **boost::polygon** library. They have an example of how to do intersections [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection.html) and differences [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/difference.html).

The intersection function is defined as follows:

```
bool intersection(Geometry1 const & geometry1, Geometry2 const & geometry2, GeometryOut & geometry_out)
```

In order to use `intersection` in a loop, and measure areas, I think I need to convert the `GeometryOut` type to the `Geometry1` type. It is not clear how to do this.

A reduced version of my code thus far is:

```
#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/multi/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
namespace gtl = boost::polygon;

typedef gtl::polygon_data<float> Polygon;

Polygon MakeBox(float xmin, float ymin, float xmax, float ymax){
  typedef gtl::polygon_traits<Polygon>::point_type Point;
  Point pts[] = {
    gtl::construct<Point>(xmin, ymin),
    gtl::construct<Point>(xmin, ymax),
    gtl::construct<Point>(xmax, ymax),
    gtl::construct<Point>(xmax, ymin)
  };
  Polygon poly;
  gtl::set_points(poly, pts, pts+4);

  return poly;
}

double GetValue(const Polygon &base, const std::vector<Polygon> &polys, const std::vector<double> &vals){
  double value     = 0;
  double base_area = gtl::area(base);
  boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<Polygon> multipoly, isect, multipolynew;
  //I've also tried the following line in place of the line above: doesn't work.
  //std::deque<Polygon> multipoly, isect, multipolynew;
  multipoly.push_back(base);

  for(int i=0;i<polys.size();i++){
    boost::geometry::intersection(multipoly, polys[i], isect);
    value    += gtl::area(isect)/base_area*vals[i];
    boost::geometry::difference(multipoly,polys[i],multipolynew);
    multipoly = multipolynew;
  }

  return value;
}

int main() {
  Polygon base = MakeBox(0,0,10,10); //Base polygon
  std::vector<Polygon> polys;
  std::vector<double>  vals;
  //Set up some random input
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    int xmin=rand()%10;
    int xmax=xmin+rand()%10;
    int ymin=rand()%10;
    int ymax=ymin+rand()%10;
    polys.push_back(MakeBox(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax));
    vals.push_back(rand()%100);
  }
  std::cout<<GetValue(base,polys,vals)<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Docs say `intersection` output can be a `multi_polygon` so no need to convert anything. And also, what do you mean by "doesn't work" in the comment?

Comment: The `multi_polyon` may work as an output of `intersection`, but it does not work as an input. It is unclear how to convert the output to a form suitable for input, as mentioned in the question. Using `std::deque<Polygon>` instead of `multi_polygon` does not lead to successful compilation either.

Comment: Well, the whole problem comes from the fact that you have an ill-defined task. You say "Difference `B` and `p_0` to form a new polygon `B_1`", when `B_1` is not a polygon. In general case it can be many disjoint polygons. So, you shouldn't think how to give a `multi_polygon` as an input - you should use a loop and think how do you want to process each part of the result. You start correctly, to have everything in terms of a multipolygon (i.e., putting `base` into a collection), but you need to add some inner loops to define what do you want to do with each of the resulting polygons.

Comment: Indeed, `B_1` is a multipolygon, but I would have expect there would be a way for boost's intersection and difference operators to act on multipolygons.

Comment: Following your comment, I have reworded the question to use the word `multipolygon`.

Comment: I would not expect that, because you can have different expectations for that operations. E.g. it could intersect them pair-wise, or each of them with all others. It could accumulate results separately (as result of each intersection could be again a collection), or all together in one collections. It's a very non-obvious operation.

Comment: While there are many potential ways to implement multipolygon operations, as you suggest, what matters is whether that affects the result. [Set algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra) holds that the intersection operator can satisfy the identity operation and is associative, commutative, and distributive. So the order of operations between two multipolygons, at least for intersection, should not matter.

Comment: The difference operator is also distributive across intersections. If you think intersection and difference operations on multipolygons are ill-defined, I invite you to convince me (possibly by submitting an answer to this question) using good references or a mathematically-structured argument, rather than simple assertions. How do you know what you think you know?

Comment: "How do you know what you think you know?" lol, what? Anyway, the example ambiguities I've described have nothing to do with mathematical definitions. They exist on the technical, implementation level - what is not obvious is the interface of such a function (please refer to my previous comment - it could accumulate and return results in many different ways). And it's obvious it's just my guessing, as I'm no mind reader of boost implementors. I'm just saying that I wouldn't be surprised if such function didn't exist, from practical reasons. You shouldn't have any trouble implementing this.

Comment: So, seems you have two different questions: 1) can you convert a multipolygon to a polygon? - the answer is, obviously no (as explained above) 2) is there a version of `intersection` and `difference` for multipolygons as inputs. Seems no, probably you can check that for yourself (or you've already did). Still, the `Geometry` concept seems quite general, so there is something to look into. Perhaps you could reword your question to focus on this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this from all angles I would conclude that this is a limitation of Boost Geometry [adaptation of Boost Polygon types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/adapted/boost_polygon/polygon_data.html).

Even when replacing the "vanilla" ring type (`boost::polygon_data<>`) by the more full featured polygon concept implementation from Boost Polygon (`boost::polygon_with_holes_data<>`) doesn't allow the adapted Polygon to be used in a `boost::geometry::multi_poygon<T>` instantiation.

In case you are interested I have some more information uncovered during my searches:

1. You can do what you wish when using Boost Geometry models instead of Boost Polygon types. There is no problem using the `multi_polygon` as a Geometry directly there:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e2c87a91392dd1e)</kbd>**

   ```
   #include <fstream>
   #include <boost/geometry/geometry.hpp>
   #include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
   #include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>
   #include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
   #include <boost/foreach.hpp>

   typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> PointType;
   using Polygon = boost::geometry::model::polygon<PointType>;

   Polygon MakeBox(float xmin, float ymin, float xmax, float ymax){
       Polygon poly;
       poly.outer().assign({
           {xmin, ymin},
           {xmin, ymax},
           {xmax, ymax},
           {xmax, ymin}
       });
       return poly;
   }

   double GetValue(const Polygon &base, const std::vector<Polygon> &polys, const std::vector<double> &vals){
       double value     = 0;
       double base_area = boost::geometry::area(base);

       boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<Polygon> multipoly, isect, multipolynew;
       multipoly.push_back(base);

       for(size_t i=0;i<polys.size();i++){
           boost::geometry::intersection(multipoly, polys[i], isect);

           value += boost::geometry::area(isect)/base_area*vals[i];
           boost::geometry::difference(multipoly,polys[i],multipolynew);

           multipoly = multipolynew;
       }

       return value;
   }

   int main()
   {
       Polygon base = MakeBox(0,0,10,10); //Base polygon
       std::vector<Polygon> polys;
       std::vector<double>  vals;
       //Set up some random input
       for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
           int xmin=rand()%10;
           int xmax=xmin+rand()%10;
           int ymin=rand()%10;
           int ymax=ymin+rand()%10;
           polys.push_back(MakeBox(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax));
           vals.push_back(rand()%100);
       }
       std::cout<<GetValue(base,polys,vals)<<std::endl;
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively you could implement a O(n log n) visitation version of intersect that intersects two collections (e.g. vectors) of Polygons even though they're not a single Geometry.

   This mailing list exchange details precisely this http://boost-geometry.203548.n3.nabble.com/intersection-of-two-vectors-of-polygons-tp2875513p2880997.html (even though the use case here is so that the individual polygon can be associated with unique bits of information (`id`s) which is hard to do with `multi_polygon`s).

   Here's a simplified adaptation of that code that does work for intersection. I suppose you'd need to do the similar approach for the `difference` call (?). I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fab5f1fe52e0005)</kbd>**

   Another relevant thread might be http://boost-geometry.203548.n3.nabble.com/Unioning-many-polygons-td3405482.html